# Filter by JPA Criteria Query with overlapping paths expressions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I am using Jpa/Hibernate to access MariaDB in a Spring Boot application

I have this Model of a customer and it's company. Where one company can be owned by another.

```
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

class customer {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Company company;
}

class Company {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ownedBy")
  private Company ownedBy;
}
```

I want to filter for all customers of the company and the customers of the companies the company owns.

e.g.

- Customer1 belong to Company (id: 1)
- Customer2 belong to Company2 (id: 2
- Company2 is owned by Company1
- querying for id = 1 -> [Customer1, Customer2]

I build the following 2 predidates to match the customer by company id or owned Company id.

```
Join join = root.join("company");
Path companyPath = join.get("id");
// creating this path lead to the other one not working any more
Path companyOwnedPath = join.join("ownedBy").get("id");
Predicate company = criteriaBuilder.equal(companyPath, id);
Predicate companyOwned = criteriaBuilder.equal(companyOwnedPath, id);
```

They both work alone so I tried to combine them with an or.

```
criteriaBuilder.or(company, companyOwned);
```

But then I only get the results matching `companyOwned`. But I found that always when I declare the `companyOwnedPath` (even without the predicate), the `company` predicate doesn't work anymore.

Is there any side effect when creating such a path?

This is the code for the whole query building.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Join;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Path;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


public interface CustomerRepositoryCustom {

  List<Customer> getByCompany(Long id, int page, int size);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepositoryCustom {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public List<Customer> getByCompany(Long id, int page, int size) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Customer> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Customer.class);
    Root<Customer> root = query.from(Customer.class);
    CriteriaQuery<Customer> select = query.select(root);

    query.where(buildCompanyPredicate(criteriaBuilder, root, id);

    TypedQuery<Customer> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(select);

    typedQuery.setFirstResult(page * size);
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(page);

    return typedQuery.getResultList();
  }

  private Predicate buildCompanyPredicate(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root root, Long id) {

    // company join
    Join join = root.join("company");   
    Path companyPath = join.get("id");    
    // creating this path lead to the other one not working any more
    Path companyOwnedPath = join.join("ownedBy").get("id");  
    Predicate company = criteriaBuilder.equal(companyPath, id);   
    Predicate companyOwned = criteriaBuilder.equal(companyOwnedPath, id); 
    return criteriaBuilder.or(company, companyOwned);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default join type for the `From.join()` method family is `INNER JOIN`, meaning that, if a company is not owned by another company, it will not be present in the result. You want `join.join("ownedBy", JoinType.LEFT)`.